# How do you read from one SQLite table while writing to another without running into locks?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using the python SQlite driver and trying to stream read from Table1 putting each row through a python function which computes something and creates another object that I am writing to another table, Table2.

But I'm running locking issues. Shouldn't SQLite be  able to so this easily? Is there some special mode I need to turn on?

I can get this to work if I read the whole stream into memory first and then write the other table by looping over the list but that isn't streaming and has issues if Table1 can't fit into memory. Isn't there a way to permit this basic kind of streaming operation?

Update

I tried the following and perhaps it's the answer

```
db = sqlite3.connect(file, timeout=30.0, check_same_thread=False,
                             isolation_level=None)
db.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal;')
```

That is I added isolation_level=None and the pragma command. This puts it into WAL (write ahead logger) mode. It seems to avoid the locking issue for my use case anyway.

Comment: can you show some code pls

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite does not lock tables but the whole database. So if I understand you correctly it will not be possible with sqlite.

For reference take a look at [sqlite locks.](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

It mentiones:

> An EXCLUSIVE lock is needed in order to write to the database file. Only one EXCLUSIVE lock is allowed on the file and no other locks of any kind are allowed to coexist with an EXCLUSIVE lock. In order to maximize concurrency, SQLite works to minimize the amount of time that EXCLUSIVE locks are held.

A possible workaround might be to create one transaction for all your reading and writing operations. Sqlite will only lock the database when the transaction is actually commited. See [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) for transactions.